# Full Month to Datetime in Excel

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula

I have a dataset that has stored its date as string using the full month instead of a number or abbreviated version. E.g.  it is stored as "September 24, 2017 at 05:20PM" in the date field instead of 092417172000 (if it was mmddyyhhmmss) or Sep 24 2017.

I am trying to get excel to recongize this as a date, but I cannot seem to figure out a way using the old methods of using left, mid, right, but that will account for only months that match length. E.g. "=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A2,13))" works for months that are four letters long, but only then.

Is there another way to convert this field to date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not the month name, it is the `at` and the missing space between AM/PM and the time.

This formula will convert it to a proper date that you then can format how ever you like:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"at ",""),"AM"," AM"),"PM", " PM")
```

[image]